# Navigation with UISegmentcontrol iphone

Tags: iphone, navigationcontroller

I have created an up/down arrow segmented control button on the right side of the navigation bar in my detail view.  How can I use these up/down arrows to change views?

Answer (score 1):

```
[mySegmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(mySegmentedControlTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
...

- (void) mySegmentedControlTapped:(id)sender {
    NSUInteger selectedOption = mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;
    if (selectedOption == upArrowIndex) {
        // swap in "up"-ward view controller
    }
    else if (selectedOption == downArrayIndex) {
        // swap in "down"-ward view controller
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, Below did the trick.


 if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
 {
  Week0 *page = [[Week0 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Week0" bundle:nil];
  [[self navigationController] pushViewController:page animated:YES];
  page.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Week 0",@"");
  [page release];
 }
 else if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
 {
  Week1 *page = [[Week1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Week1" bundle:nil];
  [[self navigationController] pushViewController:page animated:YES];
  page.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Week 1",@"");
  [page release];
 }

Comment: You may want to pop the existing view controller, or else you'll be pushing a whole bunch of view controllers onto the navigation stack (which you might want).